# Creating PDF document from Word document using java api

Tags: java, pdf, ms-word, pdf-generation

In one of my requirement I have to create a PDF from word document such that

1) There will be a page number on every page.

2) There will be line number for every line, starting from line no as 1 for each page.

Our application is written in java so Java API will be more helpful. But if it is more convenient in any other language that will be OK.

Comment: What will the word document contain?  How perfect must the PDF be?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to the most common Java PDF API :)
http://java-source.net/open-source/pdf-libraries
IText is the most famous one, This is the link for IText
http://itextpdf.com/
I hope that I helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Since word file cant be read like a `.txt` file , you will need 2 **APIs**.

One to read data from the `doc` file and another to write that data into `pdf` file.

Now to read data from the `doc` file you can use [APACHE-POI.](http://poi.apache.org/)

and to write that data into `pdf` file you can use [ITEXT](http://itextpdf.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You could try [docx4j](http://www.docx4java.org/trac/docx4j), although you would need to make a minor enhancement to support line numbering on every line, and possibly more problematically, probably use a commercial XSL FO processor.

docx4j uses XSL FO for PDF output, and line numbering isn't part of the 1.0 spec. (It is part of the [XSL 2.0 requirements spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslfo20-req/#additional-numbering))

This means you'd have to use a XSL FO processor which supports a vendor-specific extension, for example [Antenna House](http://www.antennahouse.com/xslfo/axf5-extension.htm#axf.line-number)

**UPDATE 2016 04**

From v3.3.0, docx4j defaults to using our commercial converter, which you can try at http://converter-eval.plutext.com/

Answer (score 0):

I  suggest [JODReports](http://jodreports.sourceforge.net/) or [Docmosis](http://www.docmosis.com) since you want to start with a word document.  You can dynamically insert numbered records and page breaks from a Java api so it sounds like they will be able to meet your requirements.

You haven't indicated why you want to start with a word document.  If you are strictly generating a document, you could possibly drop that requirement and use iText or docx4j.

Comment: We are creating editorial management system and asking author to submit their script...for this requirement what do you think will be a better document format that we can use?

Comment: If authors are sending you their scripts, what does that have to do with "a number for every line".  Are you changing the document they send you by adding numbers for each line?

Comment: Actually when i will send this document to Reviewer he will review it and give his feedback with respect to line no and page no.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Apache FOP(http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/) only one thing I see last update on Oct 2012 for 1.1 release. But still issue are open.