# used arabic and persian in XWPFDocument

Tags: java, converters, xwpf

I want to convert word to pdf with arabic letters,
after a little R&D I decided to use

> org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.PdfConverter

but when I write below code , the final result is left to right , and the words  Are cluttered,for example for "سعید" result in pdf is "س ع ی د" my docx is very big And not one paragraph:

```
public class ConvertWord {
    public static void ConvertToPDF(String docPath, String pdfPath) {
        try {
            InputStream doc = new FileInputStream(new File(docPath));
            XWPFDocument document = new 


            PdfOptions options = PdfOptions.create();
            options.fontEncoding("UTF-8")

            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(pdfPath));

            PdfConverter.getInstance().convert(document,out,options);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {

        } catch (IOException ex) {

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConvertWord cwoWord=new ConvertWord();
        cwoWord.ConvertToPDF("D://" + "usc.docx","D://test12.pdf");

    }



   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a workaround to fix this issue.
You need to use [ICU4J](http://site.icu-project.org/download) library.
Then:

```
String shaped = new StringBuilder(new ArabicShaping(ArabicShaping.LETTERS_SHAPE).shape(s))
.reverse().toString();
```

Although you might have some problems with Persian Unicodes. There was an issue and someone had fixed this by patching the `ArabicShaping`. I didn't find the link to it but
[here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1g9j4oH-kPbzsNqF1VZ7jFeMEjOBois0j/view?usp=sharing) is the patched code.
(I had to upload the file in my google drive so that it doesn't get deleted over time)

Also, [here](https://www.diffchecker.com/WyqPZ2O5) is a link to the code and its difference with the main code.

I changed the class name to `PersianShaping` for convenience.

Answer (score 1):

This thread: [Creating PDF document from Word document using java api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9923910/creating-pdf-document-from-word-document-using-java-api), contains other libraries you could use. I dont think this library, you are using, will support the layout options; it is also contains many bugs and doesn't support tables, graphs, page numbers as mentioned here: https://github.com/opensagres/xdocreport/wiki/XWPFConverterPDFViaIText

Comment: Which library do you offer for Persian language support?

Comment: To be honest, I havent use any of them, however, it would be easy to go through thier APIs and to check which one provide a right to left layout or somthing like that.